# permission denied when I do "npm install" in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, vps, nvs

I have a new VPS with Ubuntu installed, just clone my repo inside /var/www and when I tried to do npm install it says:  `Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir`

Also when doing `sudo npm install` I'm getting `sudo: npm: command not found`

I installed npm using nvm latest version.

When I do `whereis node` and `whereis npm` I get `/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v.21.7.1/bin`. I dont really know if this is correct path as I tried to remove all node and nvm and It is installing in the same place.

I have seen some solutions suggest upgrading the permissions with `sumo chown` but I think that is not the right approach.

Hope someone can help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/var/www` is protected so you have either to:

- install npm using sudo `sudo [absolute path to npm (which npm)] install`
- change access `sudo chmod -R 777 [the denied path]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I manage to fix it using chmod. I don't know if that is the correct way but It works!